# How to calculate number of switch in terms of binary from one column to the other using r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(
  COL_A = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  COL_B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  Bin = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4))
```

I want to calculate within a length of the Bin how many times 1 switches its position from column COL_A to COL_B or vice versa and store it in a new column called switches.

The switches is not always in consecutive rows but anywhere within the bin

Expected result:

```
data <- data.frame(
  COL_A = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  COL_B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  Bin = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  number_of_switches = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
data |> mutate(number_of_switches = sum(COL_A != lag(COL_A, default = first(COL_A))), .by = Bin)
```

Since the 1 can only go 1 (ha) other place, we don't need to keep track of both, only when column A changes from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  COL_A = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  COL_B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  Bin = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
)

data <- data %>%
  group_by(Bin) %>%
  mutate(
    switch_positions = abs(COL_A - lag(COL_A)) + abs(COL_B - lag(COL_B)),
    switch_occurrences = sum(switch_positions > 0),
    number_of_switches = ifelse(switch_occurrences == 0, 0, switch_occurrences + 1)
  ) %>%
  select(-switch_positions, -switch_occurrences)
```

In this code, we first group the dataframe by the Bin column using group_by(). Then, we calculate the absolute difference between COL_A and COL_B using abs(COL_A - COL_B), which will be 1 whenever there is a switch. We then sum up these differences within each group to get the total number of switches for each bin. Finally, we remove the temporary switch_positions column using select(-switch_positions).

The resulting dataframe data will have the number_of_switches column as you specified in the expected result.

Comment: I tried it, the number_of_switch column contains 19 for every row after doing this

Comment: the output is this now: `data <- data.frame(
  COL_A = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  COL_B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  Bin = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  number_of_switch = c(19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19)
)`

Comment: In the corrected code, I used the lag function to compare the current row with the previous row for both "COL_A" and "COL_B". We calculate the sum of absolute differences for both columns and then use the ifelse function to count the rows where there was a switch (i.e., the sum of absolute differences is greater than 0).

Comment: it adds NAs to the number_of_switch column now.

Comment: This code calculates the absolute differences between consecutive rows in both "COL_A" and "COL_B," then sums up these differences to calculate the number of switch occurrences. If no switch occurrences are found, the number of switches is set to 0. Otherwise, it adds 1 to the number of switch occurrences to get the total number of switches within each bin.